# Align equals signs between algorithms in equation

Tags: equations, align, algorithms

I currently have code similar to:

```
\documentclass[openacc]{amsart}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\nonl $\hat{\beta}_{j}^{\bullet} = \arg\min_{\beta} \left\|\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{X}\beta\right\|_2^2 + \lambda\sum_{k=1}^{p}w_k|\beta_{k}|$;\\
\bigskip
\nonl $\hat{\beta}_{j} = \arg\min_{\beta_{j}} \left\|\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{X}\beta\right\|_2^2$\\
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

But am trying to align the equals signs perfectly between the two algorithms. I've tried changing the code to:

```
\documentclass[openacc]{amsart}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\nonl $\hat{\beta}_{j}^{\bullet} = \arg\min_{\beta} \left\|\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{X}\beta\right\|_2^2 + \lambda\sum_{k=1}^{p}w_k|\beta_{k}|$;\\
\bigskip
\nonl $\hat{\beta}_{j} \ { }= \arg\min_{\beta_{j}} \left\|\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{X}\beta\right\|_2^2$\\
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

but that doesn't seem to make them perfectly aligned and seems to be a bit of only a temporary fix that doesn't truly solve the problem.

Is there a way to perfectly align the equals signs within the algorithm framework in LaTex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please extend your code fragments to complete small document, which we can test as they are.

Comment: There are several algorithm-related packages. Which one(s) do you employ? And how or where is `\nonl` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the `\nonl` command and am using the standard `algorithm` package.

Comment: OK, so how or where are `\nl` and `\oldnl` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried updating again.

Comment: Why you not use simple `align*` environment? Because horizontal lines above and below equations and their  left aligning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you (a) encase both equations in an `aligned` environment and (b) use a single `\nonl` directive, right before `\begin{aligned}`.
If you don't intend to provide a `\caption` to the algorithm, one could simply sandwich the `aligned` environment between `\hrule` directives. Both possibilities are illustrated below.

I would also define `\argmin` as a math operator in its own right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[openacc]{amsart}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line

\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
\DeclareMathOperator*\argmin{argmin}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Two aligned equations} \label{alg:2eq} % optional
\nonl%
$\begin{aligned}
\hat{\beta}_j^{\bullet} 
  &= \argmin_{\beta}   \norm{\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{X}\beta}_2^2 
     + \lambda\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^{p} w_k\abs{\beta_k};\\
\hat{\beta}_j^{\phantom{\bullet}} 
  &= \argmin_{\beta_j} \norm{\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{X}\beta}_2^2
\end{aligned}$
\end{algorithm}

\bigskip
\hrule
\smallskip
$\begin{aligned}
\hat{\beta}_j^{\bullet} 
  &= \argmin_{\beta}   \norm{\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{X}\beta}_2^2 
     + \lambda\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^{p} w_k\abs{\beta_k};\\
\hat{\beta}_j^{\phantom{\bullet}} 
  &= \argmin_{\beta_j} \norm{\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{X}\beta}_2^2
\end{aligned}$
\smallskip
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to make the $\beta_j$ as a subscript of the \argmin rather than underneath it?

Comment: @AW27 - Yes. Either change `\DeclareMathOperator*\argmin{argmin}` to `\DeclareMathOperator\argmin{argmin}` (for a global change) or `\argmin_{\beta}` to `\argmin\nolimits_{\beta}` (for a local, or one-off, change).